# Using a Classifier with a split_iterator

Tags: c++, boost

There is something about the boost string algorithms that I seem to be missing.  I am trying to use a split_iterator with a using Clasifier as the split point.  So, for example I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
make_split_iterator(str, is_space);
```

however make_split_iterator expects a Range and a Finder.  So what I need is to find some sequence to create a Finder from a Classifier.  Does anyone know how to do this, or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [token_finder](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/algorithm/token_finder.html), as in `make_split_iterator(str, token_finder(is_space()))` or `make_split_iterator(str, token_finder(is_any_of(" ")))` etc.

Full example, assuming your goal is tokenize (hence `token_compress_on`)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
int main()
{
        std::string str = "This is a      test string";

        for( boost::algorithm::split_iterator<std::string::iterator> i
            = make_split_iterator(str, token_finder(
                                        boost::algorithm::is_space(),
                                        boost::algorithm::token_compress_on));
             i != boost::algorithm::split_iterator<std::string::iterator>();
             ++i)
        {
                std::cout << *i << '\n';
        }
}
```

test run: https://ideone.com/vQ2ZM

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.  Never even thought of checking find_token, because I figured it would only be able to find a single token.